# A well-defined structure for javascript object model and organization for javascript files in an ASP .NET MVC application

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

When applying MVVM pattern using library like knockout, kendo, angular... in a MVC .NET application we probably have to deal with some concerns:

- How to organize and render scripts efficiently when those scripts only needed for this view but that view (view-specific script)?
- How to associate data between the model at server-side and the view-model at client-side without manually declaring the view-model?
- How to facilitate MVVM APIs to bind view-specific script with HTML element in view?

Below is an approach for those concerns:

- Firstly, we need some core functions allow extending JS objects in an inheritance structure. Based on jquery, it can be done in a file app.core.js like this:

  ```
  (function ($) {
      AppGlobal = function () { };
      AppGlobal.prototype = {
          DOT: '.',

          init: AppGlobal,

          namespace: function (namespace, context) {
              context = context || window;
              var index = namespace.indexOf(this.DOT);
              if (index > 0) {
                  var subNamespace = namespace.substring(index + 1);
                  var subContextName = namespace.substring(0, index);
                  context[subContextName] = context[subContextName] || {};
                  return this.namespace(subNamespace, context[subContextName]);
              }
              context[namespace] = context[namespace] || {};
              return context[namespace];
          },

          extend: function (protobj, skipBaseConstructor) {
              protobj = protobj || {};
              var subClass = null;
              var baseConstructor = this;
              if (typeof (baseConstructor) != "function") {
                  baseConstructor = this.init;
              }
              if (protobj.init) {
                  subClass = function () {
                      if (!skipBaseConstructor) {
                          baseConstructor.apply(this, arguments);
                      }
                      protobj.init.apply(this, arguments);
                  };
              }
              else {
                  subClass = function () {
                      if (!skipBaseConstructor) {
                          baseConstructor.apply(this, arguments);
                      }
                  };
                  protobj.init = baseConstructor;
              }
              subClass.prototype = subClass.prototype || {};
              $.extend(true, subClass.prototype, this.prototype, protobj);
              subClass.extend = this.extend;
              return subClass;
          },

      };
      app = new AppGlobal();
      app.Core = app.extend({
      });
  })(jQuery);
  ```
- Place that file in ~\Scripts folder and register it in bundling config at server-side:

  ```
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/app/core").Include("~/Scripts/app*"));
  ```
- We can then reference core script in a layout to be re-used in the views which are based on that layout:

  ```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
  @Scripts.Render("~/js/app/core")
  @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
  ```
- Secondly, we need a base for view-specific script objects. It, at least, needs to hold a reference to the HTML element plays as the container in the view. This will be the element to be bound with view-model and can be the scope which is very important for using jquery selector to avoid any mistakes like duplicate id, unexpected matching element,... Facilitating from jquery and knockout, it can be like this:

  ```
  (function ($, ko) {
      app.namespace("app.view").ViewBase = app.Core.extend({
          init: function (options) {
              this.element = options.element;
          }
      });
      app.namespace("app.view").KoView = app.view.ViewBase.extend({
          init: function (options) {
              var model = options.data;
              if (model) {
                  for (var prop in model) {
                      model[prop] = ko.observable(model[prop]);
                  }
                  $.extend(this, model);
              }
              ko.applyBindings(this, this.element);
          }
      });
  })(jQuery, ko);
  ```
- To be rendered in core script bundle, the script should be named app.view.js and placed in ~\Scripts folder. The mechanism that "data" and "element" being passed through parameter "options" of the constructors will be covered later.
- Next, we will work with markups of a certain view applied MVVM like, for example, view Edit of the model Customer:

  ```
  @model CustomerModel
  @{
      ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
  }
  <h2>
      Edit</h2>
  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
      <fieldset>
          <legend>Customer</legend>
          <div class="editor-label">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
          </div>
          <div class="editor-field">
              <input type="text" name="Name" data-bind="value: Name" />
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
          </div>
          <div class="editor-label">
              @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone)
          </div>
          <div class="editor-field">
              <input type="text" name="Phone" data-bind="value: Phone"/>
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone)
          </div>
          <p>
              <input type="button" value="Hello" data-bind="click: hello"/>
              <input type="submit" value="Save" />
          </p>
      </fieldset>
  }
  ```
- This view has some HTML elements binding (using knockout) with properties of CustomerModel returned from the Edit action:

  ```
  public class CustomerModel
  {
      public string Name { get; set; }

      public string Phone { get; set; }
  }

  public class CustomerController : Controller
  {
      public ActionResult Edit(int id)
      {
          var model = new CustomerModel {Name = "a name", Phone = "a number"};
          return View(model);
      }
  }
  ```

and an event handler for button "Hello".

- Normally, we have to define a view-model object at client-side that has respective properties and a function to handle button event. But going with this approach, we don't need to. To achieve that, add more functions in app.core.js:

  ```
  (function ($) {
      //...
      AppGlobal.prototype = {
          //...
          VIEW_OPTIONS: 'view-options',

          evaluate: function (expression) {
              expression = expression.replace(/(\w+ *):/g, '"$1":');
              if (!/^({.*})$/.test(expression)) {
                  expression = '({' + expression + '})';
              }
              return eval(expression);
          },

          initView: function (element, data) {
              var viewOptions = $(element).data(this.VIEW_OPTIONS);
              if (viewOptions) {
                  viewOptions = viewOptions.replace(/data *: *Model\.(.+)/i, 'data: this.$1');
                  var options = this.evaluate.apply(data, [viewOptions]);
                  var settings = { element: element, data: options.data || data };
                  if (options.options) {
                      $.extend(settings, options.options);
                  }
                  return new options.type(settings);
              }
          }
      };
      //...
  })(jQuery);
  ```
- Then extend jquery function (put in app.jquery.extensions.js and place in ~\Script folder):

  ```
  (function ($) {
      $.fn.extend({
          initViews: function (data) {
              var viewOptionsAttr = 'data-' + app.VIEW_OPTIONS
              var elements = this.find('div[' + viewOptionsAttr + '], fieldset[' + viewOptionsAttr + ']');
              var views = [];
              $(elements).each(function (index, element) {
                  var view = app.initView(element, data);
                  if (view) {
                      views.push(view);
                  }
              });
              return views;
          }
      });
      $.initViews = $.fn.initViews;
  })(jQuery);
  ```
- Before using "initViews" function, we need view-specific script Edit.js:

  ```
  (function ($) {
      app.namespace("app.view.customer").Edit = app.view.KoView.extend({
          init: function (options) {
              this.title = options.title;
              this.Phone('12345');
          },

          hello: function (e) {
              alert('Hello' + this.Name());
          }
      });
  })(jQuery);
  ```
- And using this HTML extension:

  ```
  public static IHtmlString RegisterViewScripts(this HtmlHelper helper)
  {
      var bundles = BundleTable.Bundles;
      const string virtualPath = "~/js/app/view";
      var view = helper.ViewContext.View.GetViewName();
      var path = string.Format("~/Scripts/{0}/{1}.js", 
          (string)helper.ViewContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("controller"), view);
      bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle(virtualPath).Include(path));
      return Scripts.Render(virtualPath);
  }
  ```
- Along with placing Edit.js in ~\Script\Customer, we can render it in the view Edit of Customer like below:

  ```
  @section Scripts {
      @Html.RegisterViewScripts()
  }
  ```
- After that, modify view markups to bind with "initViews":

  ```
  <fieldset data-view-options="type: app.view.customer.Edit, options: {title: '@ViewBag.Title'}">
  ```
- Finally, call to "initViews" in layout:

  ```
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
  @Scripts.Render("~/js/app/core")
  @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
  <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function(){
              $.initViews(@(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))));
          });
  </script>
  ```

to bind container element in the view ~\Views\Customer\Edit.cshtml with JS object defined in ~\Scripts\Customer\Edit.js without creating any properties in client-side view-model object.

Comment: You're mixing up things. You're using MVC with a model generated server side and then MVVM on the client, then you have two different models and technologies in a single view. That's plain wrong. Use either MVVM or MVC; but don't mix them up!

Comment: What's the question here?  If you're answering your own question you should post it as an answer